# Opencv, combination of chroma key correction and contour detection gives unexpected result

Tags: opencv

I am doing contour detection on a chroma key corrected image. Everything works fine when I filter out just the blues, but when I try to get a better chroma correction by also filtering the reds, suddenly my contours cannot be detected anymore. Anyone any suggestions?

WITH BLUE FILTER:

```
img = cv2.imread('yellowcropped.jpg', 1)
lower_blue = np.array([0, 0, 15])  ##[R value, G value, B value]
upper_blue = np.array([255, 255, 60])
mask = cv2.inRange(image_copy, lower_blue, upper_blue)
```

[image]

WITH BLUE AND RED FILTER:

```
lower_blue = np.array([180, 0, 15])  ##[R value, G value, B value]
upper_blue = np.array([255, 255, 60])
```

(notice the top left image get's much crisper, but NO CONTOURS are detected anymore.)
[image]

BELOW MY CONTOUR FINDING CODE:

```
imgContour = image_original.copy()
imgBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (7, 7), 1)
imgGray = imgBlur
imgCanny = cv2.Canny(imgGray,threshold1,threshold2)
kernel = np.ones((5, 5))
imgDil = cv2.dilate(imgCanny, kernel, iterations=1)
getContours(imgDil,imgContour)


def getContours(img,imgContour):

""" DRAWS AND FINDS CONTOURS, THEN RETURNS a list of lists incl x0, y0, w, h"""

contour_list = []
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
# print('contours:', contours)
for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    areaMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Area", "Parameters")
    if area > areaMin and area < 5000:
        cv2.drawContours(imgContour, cnt, -1, (255, 0, 0), 7)
        peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02 * peri, True)
        # print(len(approx))
        x , y , w, h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
        print('contour bounding:', x,y,w,h)
        center_x = int(x + w/2)
        center_y = int(y + h/2)

        cv2.circle(imgContour,(center_x, center_y), 5, (0, 0, 255), 5)
        cv2.rectangle(imgContour, (x , y ), (x + w , y + h ), (0, 255, 0), 5)

        cv2.putText(imgContour, "Points: " + str(len(approx)), (x + w + 20, y + 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, .7,
                    (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(imgContour, "Area: " + str(int(area)), (x + w + 20, y + 45), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.7,
                    (0, 255, 0), 2)

        if area < 3500:
            cv2.putText(imgContour, "THIS IS A SMALL PART" , (x + w + 20, y + 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.7,
                        (0, 255, 0), 2)

        contour_list.append([x,y,w,h])

return contour_listenter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

So i still do not entirely know what went wrong here but I found a solution for anyone in the future looking to first chroma key correct (Remove background) and then do contour detection:

[image]

I dropped the gaussian filter, dilate and canny and instead just inverted the image's colours (contour detection only detects white parts on black background) using:

```
mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
```

I then changed the contour detection from cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL to cv2.RETR_LIST

Somehow that fixed it, the result is now really good.